# Building an url address that contains an email address as username with Uri.Builder

Tags: java, android, url, uri

I'm using this piece of code to build the url that is sent to a server with POST request.

```
    Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
    builder.scheme("https").encodedAuthority("serverAddressWithPortHere").appendPath("path1").appendPath("path2").
            appendPath("login").appendQueryParameter("userName", email).
            appendQueryParameter("passWord", password).
            appendQueryParameter("deviceId", "1");
    url = builder.build().toString();
```

The problem is that an email address would contain the sign '@' as you'd expect and Uri.Builder turns it into '%40'.

I'm supposed to get "blabla@mail.com" but what I get is "blabla%40mail.com"

How should I implement this?

Comment: You send the email and password to server?

Comment: Yeah exactly. That's how the web service is built.

Comment: Can you post the server code?

Comment: I can't, but I tested it using Postman and it works and returns the JSON string I want when the '@' sign is in it.

Comment: I have a suggestion that is to send the email and password and in server convert %40 to @.